# MKTime - error if month is different

Tags: php

I need to check whether the departure-date is after the arrivaldate.

For example:

```
arrivaldate 13/3/2012 departure 14/3/2012 -> error = false
arrivaldate 13/3/2012 departure 12/3/2012 -> error = true

$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$arrivaldd,$arrivalmm,$arrivalyy);

$timestamp2 = mktime(0,0,0,$departuredd,$departuremm,$departureyy);

if ($timestamp2 <= $timestamp) {$error1 = true;} else {$error1 = false;}
```

It works fine, but $error is set false if arrivaldate is 31/3/2012 and departure date 1/4/2012.

Comment: also, it is totally fine that "error" is set "false" when departure is after arrival. (which is the case for arrivaldate = 31/3/2012 and departure = 1/4/2012) .. please ask more precise!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this function mktime parameters are as follows

```
mktime(hrs,min,sec,month,day,year)
```

and you are giving day first and then month.so timestamp generated is departure higher than arrival so you are getting error

Answer (score 3):

`mktime` expects is parameters in the following order: hour, minute, second, month, day, year. You have the day and month in reversed order. See the [PHP.net reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 2):

That's because [mktime](http://ca.php.net/mktime)'s arguments are:

```
mktime(hours, minute, seconds, month, day, year);
```

You've got the month/day arguments reversed